# How Do I Order Posts by Modified Date?

Tags: order

I've read the codex article about [`WP_Query`'s `orderby` parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and I understood that it is possible to order by Modified date. But I couldn't find where should I edit.

How WordPress post order by modified date including home page as well as categories page and tag pages?

Comment: With everything I explained in the duplicate, and with the use of the appropriate conditionals, it should work exactly the same, no difference

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
function my_custom_ordering( $query ) {
    if($query->is_main_query() AND !is_admin() ) {
      if ( $query->is_home() ||  $query->is_category() ||  $query->is_tag() ){
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
       }
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_ordering' );
```

This will set `orderby` field to `modified` in the WordPress query.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, with GeneratePress.

Answer (score 3):

```
function orderby_modified_posts( $query ) {
    if($query->is_main_query()) {
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
       }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'orderby_modified_posts' );
```

This should alter all archives.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function modified( $query )
{
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_search() || $query->is_archive() )  )
    {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modified' );

?>
```